Race Condition in tbb::concurrent_vector When Accessing size() in Parallel Node Insertion
I am using tbb::concurrent_vector nodes_ to add multiple nodes to a tree in parallel. The issue arises when I attempt to return nodes_.size(). A race condition occurs when two threads add a node concurrently, causing nodes_.size() to not return the desired outcome.
While I could use a mutex to address this race condition, it would negate the benefits of adding nodes in parallel, making concurrent_vector unnecessary.
Is there a way to continue using concurrent_vector while avoiding race conditions with size()?
Here’s a simplified version of my code, that is run in parallel by multiple threads
int PTree::makeNode(int item) {
  nodes_.push_back(PNode(item));
  return nodes_.size() - 1;
}


What makes you say that the value is incorrect? If you call the function twice, it may return 1 and 2 or 2 and 2 and both are correct.

size() is race-free but of course it is not atomic with the push_back. I assume you want to know the position where the element was inserted? Well, push_back returns an iterator. I presume std::distance(nodes_.begin(), iterator) will give you the answer. Iterators stay valid across push_back operations

@TedLyngmo I edited the posted, I meant the desired result, meaning the size() after adding the node but without considering the other threads that might have added nodes at the same time

Well, then Ahmed's answer is the solution.

In tbb:concurrent_vector using size() to find the position of the last element you inserted is wrong, you cannot do both operations atomically, instead use the returned iterator from push_back()
int PTree::makeNode(int item) {
  auto it = nodes_.push_back(PNode(item));
  return static_cast<int>(std::distance(nodes_.begin(), it));
}

godbolt demo
